# get max of value - lead and keep corresponding rows that generated the max using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, max, lead

How would one keep the corresponding two rows (all columns preserved) that produced the **max** difference after grouping, arranging, and subtracting the 4th lead from the current value? I can currently use top_n to pluck out one row (see sample code below). Have easily used reframe to get the max difference after grouping, but keep the rows that produced that max is taking longer than expected. Thanks.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  arrange(DateTime)%>%
  mutate(new_column = value- lead(value,n=4L)) %>%
  top_n(1,new_column)
```

Comment: You could make this much easier for people to answer if you could edit your question to include some sample data (best to run `dput(df)` and paste the output) and an example of the output you expect.

Comment: In particular, the two relevant rows are the two from which the difference was calculated, per group? probably some use of which.max and subtraction of the index will work for this

Answer (score 1):

You are leading, which works by position, so you need to track positions, row_number() is good for that.

Here is an approach

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(42)
(df <- data.frame(
  group=rep(letters[1:2],each=10),
  DateTime =rep(1:10,2),
  value  = sample.int(100,size=20,replace=TRUE)
))

(df_arr <-  df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  arrange(DateTime)%>%
  mutate(rn=row_number()))

(original_sol_df <-df_arr |> mutate(
         new_column = value- lead(value,n=4L)) %>%
  top_n(1,new_column))

(stub_df <- original_sol_df |> select(group,rn))

(prep_1 <- bind_rows(stub_df,
                     mutate(stub_df,
                            rn=rn+4L)))

fin_df <- left_join(prep_1,
                    df_arr,
                    by = join_by(group, rn))
```

Comment: thank you kindly, this will be useful going forward. thought to index a in a forloop but was certain there was a way to "merge"/join.